# How to remove a list of indices from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists of lists of the same length in Python 3 as follows:

```
A = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
W = [[2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 4], [1, 1, 3, 4]]
```

Elements of `A` are indices of elements of `W`. I would like to remove the elements of `W` given `A`. So, in the example, I would like to remove `W[0][0]`, `W[1][0]`, `W[1][1]`, `W[2][0]`, `W[2][1]`, `W[2][2]`, etc.

What I did is this:

```
for t in range(len(A)):
    del W[t][A[t]]
```

But this gives the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Comment: Have you printed out `A[t]` in this loop? Your mistake (and how to approach this problem) should become obvious then.

Comment: It prints `[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3]`, where is the problem? I understand the error but I cannot fix it.

Comment: They are lists. You have to retrieve each integer from each list and delete the element from the corresponding W list. The function [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) makes it easier to synchronise these two tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike `numpy` arrays, you cannot index a list with a list. But you can use a list comprehension for this task:

```
A = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
W = [[2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 4], [1, 1, 3, 4]]

res = [[j for i, j in enumerate(w) if i not in a] for a, w in zip(A, W)]

print(res)

[[2], [3], [3], [4, 4], []]
```

---

Or, if you are happy using a 3rd party library, `numpy` syntax is simpler:

```
import numpy as np

res = [np.delete(i, j).tolist() for i, j in zip(W, A)]
```

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use two nested loops. As you have probably noticed by now, you need two index numbers - one for the list in A and another for the element number of this list. Here is one way to tackle the problem:

```
A = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
W = [[2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 4], [1, 1, 3, 4]]

#cycle through list A and keep track of the list number i
for i, a_list in enumerate(A):
    #retrieve index from each list in A, start with the highest index to avoid index problems
    for j in sorted(a_list, reverse = True):
        #delete the element j in list i of W
        del W[i][j]

print(W)
#output
#[[2], [3], [3], [4, 4], []]
```